# Extract Numeric info from Pandas column using regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex, text-extraction

I am trying to extract the highlighted "numeric information" from a Pandas DataFrame column:

| Text |
| --- |
| Dimensions: `23"/60` |
| Dimensions: `23" / 60` |
| Dimensions: `48"` |
| Dimensions: `22.5X8.25` |
| Dimensions: `80IN` |
| Dimensions: `567 S` |
| Dimensions: `22.5X8.25` |
| Dimensions: `26INNP` |
| Dimensions: `24" x 55"` with pipe `16 x 7` |

I am using regex and is as follows: `regex = r"(\d([^\s]*)\s.\s\d*[^\s])|(\d([^\s])*)"`

I am using to the below script to create a new column with all the numeric information extracted from each sentence and combined with '_'

```
df2['Numeric_Info'] = df2['Text'].apply(lambda x: '_'.join([i[0] for i in re.findall(regex, str(x))]))
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Edit:

Specifying rules to the pattern to solidify the regex:

- Sentences containing words with numbers should be extracted (for sentence `short A20-6014 complete`, `A20-6014` should be extracted)
- Sentences beginning with words with numbers should be extracted (for sentence `A20-6014 short complete`, `A20-6014` should be extracted)
- Sentences ending with words with numbers should be extracted (for sentence `short complete A20-6014`, `A20-6014` should be extracted)
- Two letter words in between words containing numbers should be considered (ie. for sentence `ELBOW- 2.5 IN 90 SIL`, `2.5 IN 90` should be extracted)
- Greater than 2 letter words in between words containing numbers should extracted separately and joined with a `_`. This also applies for alphanumeric words occurring at two different places in a sentence (ie. for sentence `ELBOW- 2.5 IND 90 SIL`, `2.5_90` should be extracted. )
- Another Test Case: for a sentence `90 CONN 3/4 ST-#8 FL`, `90_3/4_ST-#8` should be extracted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
regex = r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?"?(?:\s*[Xx/.]\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?"?)?(?:\s*[A-Z]+\b)?'
df2['Numeric_Info'] = df2['Text'].str.findall(regex).str.join('_')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cYX4Ow/1).

*Details*:

- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - an int or float value
- `"?` - an optional `"` char
- `(?:\s*[Xx/.]\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?"?)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\s*[Xx/.]\s*` - `X`, `x`, `/` or `.` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - an int or float value
  - `"?` - an optional `"` char
- `(?:\s*[A-Z]+\b)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `[A-Z]+` - one or more ASCII uppercase letters
  - `\b` - a word boundary.

Here is a Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text':['No data here','Dimensions: 23"/60', 'Dimensions: 23" / 60', 'Dimensions: 48"', 'Dimensions: 22.5X8.25', 'Dimensions: 80IN', 'Dimensions: 567 S','Dimensions: 22.5X8.25', 'Dimensions: 26INNP','Dimensions: 24" x 55" with pipe 16 x 7']})
regex = r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?"?(?:\s*[Xx/.]\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?"?)?(?:\s*[A-Z]+\b)?'
df['Numeric_Info'] = df['Text'].str.findall(regex).str.join('_')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                     Text      Numeric_Info
0                            No data here                  
1                      Dimensions: 23"/60            23"/60
2                    Dimensions: 23" / 60          23" / 60
3                         Dimensions: 48"               48"
4                   Dimensions: 22.5X8.25         22.5X8.25
5                        Dimensions: 80IN              80IN
6                       Dimensions: 567 S             567 S
7                   Dimensions: 22.5X8.25         22.5X8.25
8                      Dimensions: 26INNP            26INNP
9  Dimensions: 24" x 55" with pipe 16 x 7  24" x 55"_16 x 7
```

Comment: @Parsh I know, I follow your post. The last test case is not in line with the other rules, so I do not think I can help more than coming up with [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/cYX4Ow/2).

Comment: could you help as to why this does not capture words like `1st`, `2nd`, `3rd` and so on. Aren't they similar to the other ones?

Comment: @Parsh Please provide a sample string.

Comment: Sure. For instance, `Dimensions: 80th flag`. Should it not capture `80th`

Comment: @Parsh you may use [this regex then](https://regex101.com/r/cYX4Ow/3).